# Problem getting XML elements in an SVG file

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am trying to read a very basic SVG file which has the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="600" height="300" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g stroke="black" >
        <line x1="75" y1="160" x2="525" y2="160" stroke-width="10"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

I am trying to get a collection of line elements.  However, the following code does not work:

```
XDocument XD = XDocument.Load(PathToFile);
XElement SVG_Element = XD.Root;
var adam = SVG_Element.Elements("line");
```

Upon inspecting the variables, the document is loaded properly, but the variable "adam" remains null, as if it does not find any elements with that name.  Any help is appreciated.

**Edit**: Using Descendants does not fix this.  It still comes up empty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alright guys, I did figure this out.  Apparently I need to specify the namespace as part of the QName:

```
var adam = SVG_Element.Descendants("{http://www.w3.org/2000/svg}line");
```

Comment: Had similar issue. Figured out by using **`xdoc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();`** and then **`xdoc.Root.Element($"{{{ns}}}defs");`** ...

Comment: This sorted me out. Thanks very much @Adam S

Answer (score 0):

The line element is a grandchild of the root, not a child.  Try the Descendants() method of the XDocument instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Unfortunately, even using descendants does not give me anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Dim xmldoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("PathtosvgFile"))

        Dim Info As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = _
            From typeElement In xmldoc.Descendants.Descendants
            Where typeElement.Parent = "g"
            Select typeElement

        Dim tel As XElement

        For Each tel In Info.DescendantsAndSelf.Distinct()
         'Access each descendant here and do something.
        Next
```

Answer (score -1):

I never used XDocument to parse Xml files. I use XmlDocument. But I believe both work on a similar fashion.
My guess is that you should first query for the "g" element, and then for the "line" element, something like the following:

```
XDocument XD = XDocument.Load(PathToFile);
XElement SVG_Element = XD.Root;
var gs = SVG_Element.Elements("g");
var adam = gs[0].Elements("line");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It can't find the "g" element, either.

Answer (score -1):

```
XDocument SVGDoc = XDocument.Load(yourfile);
XElement svg_Element = SVGDoc.Root;

IEnumerable<XElement> gElement = from e1 in svg_Element.Elements("{http://www.w3.org/2000/svg}g")
                                 select e1;
int nCounter = 0;
foreach (XElement myElement in gElement)
{
    ... 
}
```

Comment: As is, your answer is not helpful.  Please consider explaining ***why*** this might be the right solution.

Comment: Also, this was already answered with basically the same answer, but shorter and without superfluous code, 6 years ago.